# How to properly convert parameters to const char *?

Tags: c++, vector, constants

I got the following errors while compiling, here's the problem part of code. Please help me understand what's wrong?

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = files.begin(), end = files.end(); i != end; ++i)

   {
       printf("%s%s\n", parm.c_str(), i->c_str());

       TiXmlElement *fileElement = new TiXmlElement("File");

       fileElement->SetAttribute("name", *i); // error C2664

       parentElement->LinkEndChild(fileElement);

   }

   files.clear();



   for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = subFolders.begin(), end = subFolders.end(); i != end; ++i)

   {
       printf("%s%s\n", parm.c_str(), i->c_str());

       TiXmlElement *fileElement = new TiXmlElement("Folder");

       folderElement->SetAttribute("name", *i); //error C2227

       parentElement->LinkEndChild(folderElement);

       PrintDir(parm + *i + "\\", folderElement);

   }
```

**error C2664**: void TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(const char *,const char *): cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const char *';
**error c2065** folderElement undeclared identifier;
**error C2227** left of '->SetAttribute' must point to class/struct/union;

Comment: `.c_str` will get a non-modifiable C style string from a `std::string`. Also probably already asked/answered here.

Comment: In your second for loop do the same thing which you have done in the first one `i->c_str()`

Comment: First loop sorts files and second sorts folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, in your second for loop, folderElement is undeclared. I think you meant to name it folderElement instead of fileElement. So change this line:

```
TiXmlElement *fileElement = new TiXmlElement("Folder");
```

to

```
TiXmlElement *folderElement = new TiXmlElement("Folder");
```